# What PF Selector do I need to achieve my expected update on an ajax event?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I'm relative new with JSF (Primefaces 3.5 implementation) and I need some help with one issue I'm having.

I want to hide and show two `h:selectOneMenu` depending of one `p:selectBooleanButton` my problem is that it is affecting some others `h:inputText` (clears its values) of the form because my update declaration refers to the panel where all form elements are.

How can I declare the update to just affect the `h:selectOneMenu`s? any other workaround may be a good alternative.

This is the relevant part of my xhtml:

```
<h:body>
...
<p:dialog id="detailDialog" widgetVar="detailDialog" header="Detail of someTO">
    <h:form id="detailForm">
        <p:panelGrid id="detailPanel" columns="2">
            <h:outputText value="Fancy Flag" />
            <p:selectBooleanButton value="#{myManageBean.someTO.fancyFlag}" immediate="true"
                onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" onIcon="ui-icon-check" offIcon="ui-icon-close">
                <p:ajax update="detailPanel" />
            </p:selectBooleanButton>

            <h:outputText value="Catalog" />
            <h:selectOneMenu id="fooCatalog" value="#{myManageBean.someTO.catalogValue}" rendered="#{myManageBean.someTO.fancyFlag}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{myManageBean.fooCatalog}" var="foo" itemLabel="#{foo.desc}" itemValue="#{foo.value}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="barCatalog" value="#{myManageBean.someTO.catalogValue}" rendered="#{!myManageBean.someTO.fancyFlag}">
                <f:selectItems value="#{myManageBean.barCatalog}" var="bar" itemLabel="#{bar.desc}" itemValue="#{bar.value}" />
            </h:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputText value="String Attribute" />
            <h:inputText value="#{myManageBean.someTO.stringAttr}" />

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Actualizar" update=":altaParametro:parameterTable, :growl"
                    oncomplete="handleSubmitRequest(xhr, status, args, 'detailDialog','newForm');"
                    actionListener="#{parameterBean.doUpdateParameterTO}" styleClass="pull-right"/>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
...
```

Code I've already try and doesn't run/work:

```
<p:ajax update="fooCatalog, barCatalog" />

<p:ajax update=":fooCatalog, :barCatalog" />

<p:ajax update=":detailPanel:fooCatalog, :detailPanel:barCatalog" />
```

Thank you.

Comment: It works with @Jaqen suggestion, but it doesn't make sense to me that in order to update B and C elements they must be wrapped with panel A and then update this one... in my opinion its buggy, anyway thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried your code but I'm guessing the problem is that you can't update something client side that hasn't been rendered - if its not in the resulting html ajax can't update it.

So try to wrap them in for example a panelGroup:

```
<h:panelGroup id="catalogs"> 
    <h:selectOneMenu .... />
    <h:selectOneMenu .... />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Then use your first option with the new id

```
<p:ajax update="catalogs" />
```